# angular 9 component rendering

Tags: angular, angular9

I upgraded an angular 8 application to angular 9. I'm seeing some rendering changes in the DOM.

In Angular 8, the rendering component will be at the top of the current component. But in Angular 9, it another way around.

**angular 8 renders**

[image: angular 8 rendering]

**angular 9 renders**

[image: angular 9 rendering]

Is there any reason for this change or any setting is required?

Comment: are those components lazy loaded or in other words can you show routing?

Comment: It's not lazy loading. Just normal routing using the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1):

Angular 9 uses Ivy for rendering the template.
"Ivy is the code name for Angular's next-generation compilation and rendering pipeline. With the version 9 release of Angular, the new compiler and runtime instructions are used by default instead of the older compiler and runtime, known as View Engine."
[Ivy documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ivy)

If nothing else changed in your code, this is the reason why:
https://angular.io/guide/ivy

Comment: Thank you for sharing Ivy documentation. As you mentioned, there is no change in the code. Just a library up-gradation. The documentation is not having information about the DOM rendering. I guess Ivy default rendering as such.